# fgetcsv() not reading Arabic characters

Tags: php, fgetcsv

When trying to import a CSV file, Arabic characters vanish when running `fgetcsv`, yet when I print the output from `fopen`, the Arabic characters are displayed just fine. The strange thing is that this is only happening in our production environment and not in my development environment, where `fgetcsv` reads the Arabic characters just fine. Is there some server setting that's not set correctly in production?

Comment: what is the encoding of csv file?

Comment: Can't reproduce: I created a test file in Arabic in utf8. fgetcsv worked correctly.

Comment: Can you post the file?

Comment: The CSV file uses UTF-8 encoding, but as lafor pointed out, the issue was that the locale was not set properly in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgetcsv()` makes assumptions about the file's encoding based on the system locale. As the PHP manual states:

> Locale setting is taken into account by this function. If `LANG` is e.g.
>   `en_US.UTF-8`, files in one-byte encoding are read wrong by this
>   function.

You might want to compare the locale settings on your two machines and either permanently change it on one of them, or use something like `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ar_AE.utf8')` (the second argument would obviously depend on your file's encoding) before your `fgetcsv()`.

Comment: It doesn't apply because Arabic will never be one-byte encoding.

Comment: @pguardiario I know, but the system locale might as well be UTF-16 based.

Comment: Thanks! The locale was apparently not set properly on the production server. Using `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')` before `fgetcsv` did the trick.