# Php importing and exporting from excel csv file chinese font are messed up with ??? and different symbols

Tags: php, csv, import, export

I just want to import and export product data which is in different language from a database table using php file. Other language except chinese language are good but chinese fonts are messed up.

I have used for export functioality:-

```
      mb_convert_encoding($results[$i]->name, "UTF-16LE");
```

For import functioality

```
       header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

       $data = array_map("utf8_encode", $data);
```

Comment: you're passing in utf16 to a function which expects iso8859. That'll mangle your text totally. Why not just convert DIRECTLY to utf8 with mb_convert_encoding()? That'll save you the extra step later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
```

before getting content from file. It will fetch and parse content in any other languages.

Reference: [fgetcsv() not reading Arabic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282803/fgetcsv-not-reading-arabic-characters/18283111#18283111)